# Is there any merit to extending the tags Wiki?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki

We have Wiki pages for tags such as:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Which has a lot of effort and great resources poured into it.

There's a few things I've noticed regarding this:

- It's not highly visible; new users won't find this page
- It looks like there's room to expand
- It's limited scope because of it's one-page format
- There's potential to put other useful content in here.

Is there some useful way to extend our existing tag-wiki, or is it entirely perfect the way it is?

Comment: [There's a badge for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/254/tag-editor)

Comment: I've thought that perhaps an 'about' link should be added to the tag pop-ups.

Comment: Almost everything there is a "one-page format"; that doesn't seem to have any adverse effect on scope. I don't think that's a real problem. Even Wikipedia doesn't have multiple page articles.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: It's there. It's called "info".

Comment: @Cody What if we wanted to extend from "about page" into "Tutorials, concepts, libraries ... etc"

Comment: Use title headings. In markdown, for example: `##Tutorials` or `###Tutorials`. There's no reason to spread that across multiple pages.

Comment: Bah.  Right you are @hammar.  Thanx.

Answer (score 4):

If the edit helps understanding when a tag should be used, lists possibly related tags, or refer to resources that could be useful for who is interested in questions tagged with that tag, then the edit has its merit.

It is not true that the page is not visible; if you click on [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) you are taken to the page that lists all the question using that tag, and (on the top of the page) you find the link [about the javascript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) that takes to that page. It is less visible than other pages, but it is still possible to reach it.

Comment: To add only slightly, I doubt newbies would care to look for this information -- they're much more concerned with posting questions & answers.  As they become more attune to the Stack Exchange system, I believe that they'll easily run across this webpage.

Comment: That's sort of the point, though. The focus of the system is questions and answers. Everything else is just a bonus.

Comment: @M. Tibbits Why not connect the Wiki knowledge base with the question and answers? Or provide another venue for solutions to come from.

Answer (score 2):

See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/

The tag wikis (in particular the excerpts) finally have the place they deserve in the tagging process.