# Select the first tag by default in the question's Tags box

Tags: feature-request, tags

When typing the tags for a question, it would be nice if the first tag was selected by default. Most of the time, that's the tag we want but since it's not selected, typing "Enter" posts the question instead of choosing the tag.

Comment: You might also want to submit this as an answer [to this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100669/feedback-wanted-improved-tag-editor). SO asked for feedback on newly designed tag editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think <kbd>Enter</kbd> key should be for submitting the form. Even if you use <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for tag selection, hitting the key twice would still submit the form.

This is what I do when submitting questions. It works like a charm, all the time. :-)

Enter your tag phrase. It need not be the complete word, just part of it should do.

[image: Enter tag]

You will get a list of tags matching the criteria. Use the <kbd>down</kbd> arrow to get to the tags list and press <kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>left</kbd> arrow (*if you went too far*) to navigate the list of tags. Hit <kbd>space bar</kbd> to pick the right one.

[image: Select tag]

There it is, the tag of my choice.

[image: There it is]

I think that is wonderful and simple. If I have to pick the first tag, I have to press <kbd>down</kbd> arrow and hit <kbd>space bar</kbd>.

Just my thoughts that I like the way it currently works.

Comment: Good writeup. Tab also works as an alternative to down-arrow (and Enter also works for choosing, but of course only after selecting something)

Comment: @balpha: Thanks. Good to know that I have more options to choose a tag.

Comment: I would suggest that [Tab] be used to select the currently-highlighted suggestion instead of for navigation. Many autocomplete dialogs do it that way. Arrows could still be used for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that the expected/wanted behavior will diverge amongst users, i for one would absolutely not want that.