# No tag suggestions are shown when attempting to edit a question while editing tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits, tag-autocomplete

I found one edge case where the [new and improved tag editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100669/feedback-wanted-improved-tag-editor) does not get displayed.

Steps to reproduce (10k users only):

1. While looking at a question, click the "edit tags" link next to the existing tags.
2. Without clicking either the "Save Tag Edits" or "Cancel" buttons, suddenly realize that you might as well fix some typos at the same time, so click the "edit" link to edit the question.
3. The input field for the tags will now lack all of the cool features that it usually has. In fact, not only is the new and improved tag editor not shown, even the old one is missing in action. There appears to be no tag suggestions/auto-completion whatsoever.

This has been successfully reproduced in Chrome (latest version) on Windows 7.

Comment: This is a good find and looks like it hasn't gotten much attention yet. I can successfully reproduce, so I took the liberty of editing your question to make the steps to repro even clearer. If you'd like to add what browser/OS version you're using to the question, that would be great.

Comment: @CodyGray, that info's no longer necessary, in light of the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice find. The tag editor (and other code) relies on the assumption that only one tag editor exists in the page. That's obiously a reasonable assumption, but you've found an edge case where it isn't guaranteed, since even if the old tageditor is *hidden*, it still *exists* in the page.

Of course that's not very useful anyway, so after the next build, switching to full editing will now end the tag-only inline editing.