# 'Edit tags' sometimes not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, inline-tag-editor

At odds, when I try to edit a question's tags, I get this error when clicking 'Save Tag Edits':

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined

The corresponding code appears to be inside `inline-tag-editing.js`:

```
var disableButtons = function() {
    jTagList.find('input[type="button"]').attr('disabled', 'true');
};
```

This is happening on Chrome 13.

Could this possibly be solved? I understand it might be difficult with so little information but again I'm not sure how to reproduce since it does not always happen.

**Edit:** I see why it happened. When I edit a post (full edit including title/body), then save it, and then edit only the tags (with the inline tag editor), I get this error.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: @random: I just cleared it. I will edit when it happens again or if I don't experience it anymore.

Comment: @random: It was not my cache. Please see my edit.

Comment: Maybe it's related to this recent bug? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102485/no-tag-suggestions-are-shown-when-attempting-to-edit-a-question-while-editing-tag

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: It might be, although that one is fixed.

Comment: ah yes, I have reproed this before. Has to do with doing an inline full edit, *then* a tag edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a timing issue causing a JavaScript object to be overwritten with another one too early (because a JS file was included several times) in certain cases. We've switched to loading the inline tag editing code via our deferred JavaScript loader; among other advantages, this causes the file to only be loaded once, fixing this problem.

Comment: not deployed to SO yet, but will be shortly

Comment: I can confirm this is working now. Thanks!