# Tag editor misinterprets backspace at beginning of text when text is selected

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-autocomplete

It seems that this was [already mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100669/feedback-wanted-improved-tag-editor/101343#101343), but since I just came across this issue myself and the tag editor has been fully deployed, I opted to turn it into a formal bug report. If you select text that borders a tag to the left in the tag editor, and press the backspace key, it de-tagifies the tag to the left and doesn't delete the selected text.

Example:

[image: tag editor gone haywire]

It looks like the keydown handler for the text field only lets the backspace event through if the caret start position is greater than zero. It should also take into account the situation where text is selected when the backspace key is pressed, with something like the following change (referencing the minified code function `P(U)`):

```
case 8:
    if (!T || W !== J.caret().end) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: For more fun, with your cursor at the end of your 2nd "reputation" in your example, hit shift+left-arrow or ctrl+shift+left-arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope; the issue was actually something else: The mere fact that you were able to select text while still having styled tags. That was not supposed to be possible, but wasn't prevented in all cases (it is now). All other code (including the snippet you mention) relies on that.

The reason is this: In our reinvented text box, assume you are editing the last tag. You press the shift key and the press the left arrow over and over again, creating a selection. At some point, you have reached the beginning of that tag, so what you rightfully expect is that pressing Shift-Left a few more times also selects the last letters of the previous tag.

At the moment you "crossed the border" between the tags, the previous tag has to turn from styled to editable, in other words, we have to change the content of the *actual* input box. Unfortunately, you can't change the input box content without losing the selection. Of course we could *remember* the selection and, after changing the content, re-select the correct part.

But: It ain't gonna work. If we did that, and you pressed Shift-Left again, your selection suddenly wouldn't grow at the beginning; it would shrink at the end.

Until there is good browser support for the [`selectionDirection` property](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-textarea/input-selectiondirection) (Firefox was the first to implement it, and that was a few weeks ago), there is no way to set the selection correctly in this case (you also can't *get* the direction of the selection, but it may be possible to work around this by remembering the "evolution" of the selection – it doesn't matter, because there's no way to *set* a backwards-facing selection).

This problem is the reason why as soon as there is *any* selection, we immediately bail out and just make the whole content editable.

Comment: Ah, I guess that is more consistent with the other behaviours (like pressing Shift + End). Makes sense.