# Last tag not rendering as a tag

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags

I've noticed this over the past few days and at first I thought it was a bug (see edit).

Can we have it so that IFF there exists a single matching tag to the text entered that it renders the last tag as a tag and not as text when focus is lost on the tags box:

[image]

The system already does this when you save your question, but its not clear currently whether the last tag will or won't be saved (yes, I know it does).

Comment: It *will* render if you put a space after it. Or put your cursor on *another* tag before making it lose focus.

Comment: @Shog9 - The space habit sounds like a good quick win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to behave in the way you describe; see [Feedback wanted: Improved tag editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100669/feedback-wanted-improved-tag-editor/100689#100689) for the reasons for changing it. Short version: Both behaviors make sense in a way; we've settled for the one that seems to cause fewer issues, both usability-wise and technical.